# How to manipute a data to get a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python and pandas and trying to learn data manipulation. 
I have the following data:

```
F1="green red blue yellow " 
F2="blue orange red green"
F3="yellow red"
F4="orange blue red blue"
F5="green yellow orange blue"

files =[F1,F2,F3,F4,F5]
words =  set(F1.split()+F2.split()+F3.split()+F4.split()+F5.split())
```

How can I create a pandas dataframe of the counts of words in respective file?

#### Output

```
          F1   F2   F3   F4   F5
green     1    1    0    0    1
red       1    1    1    1    0
blue      1    1    0    2    1
yellow    1    0    1    0    1
orange    0    1    0    1    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `str.get_dummies`:

```
df = (pd.Series([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5], 
                index=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
        .str.get_dummies(' ')
        .T
     )
```

Output:

```
        F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
blue     1   1   0   1   1
green    1   1   0   0   1
orange   0   1   0   1   1
red      1   1   1   1   0
yellow   1   0   1   0   1
```

---

**Update** if there are duplicates within each rows, then you need `value_counts` instead of `get_dummies`:

```
df = (pd.Series([F1,F2,F3,F4,F5], 
                index=['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5'])
        .str.split().explode()
        .groupby(level=0).value_counts()
        .unstack(level=0,fill_value=0)
     )
```

Output:

```
        F1  F2  F3  F4  F5
blue     1   1   0   2   1
green    1   1   0   0   1
orange   0   1   0   1   1
red      1   1   1   1   0
yellow   1   0   1   0   1
```

Comment: Hey, 
I was able to do this, but with a big for loop. Thanks for sharing the code. 
But, in F4 the 'blue' comes twice. This doesn't capture the repeated count.